# Justification for "running" cosmological constant

Tags: cosmology, time, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I am looking for papers which seek out to justify that the cosmological "constant" could be time-dependent. I am aware that within the framework of GR the cosmological constants really has to be a constant. But outside the framework of GR are there any physical arguments that speak for dark energy to be dynamic?
I have been looking for papers but I can't find anything reasonable.

Comment: "Outside of GR", what does "cosmological constant" even mean?

Comment: Well, I am thinkin that a quantum gravity theory would have to explain dark energy as well and in that framework dark energy might be dynamic.

Comment: The broader term including “running cosmological constant” is “dark energy”. Consequently, googling for dark energy should produce the papers you are looking for, like this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5870 .